# Alterar cor de radio button

Tags: android, android-layout, radiobutton

Tenho um aplicativo que possui fundo preto. Em uma das telas do aplicativo tenho um `RadioButton`. Eu preciso alterar a cor desse RadioButtom para que ele apareça na tela.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New RadioButton"
    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:buttonTint="#FFF" />
```

O problema é que em versões mais antigas do Android isso não funciona, ou seja, a cor não é alterada. Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso?

Comment: Breno, conseguiu resolver seu problema com a resposta? Ou precisa de mais alguma informação?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem várias alternativas, uma delas é criar um `RadioButton` personalizado usando duas imagens:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim você pode criar um `radio_button_personalizado` utilizando-as:

*`radio_button_personalizado.xml`*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checkedradiobutton" />
     <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/unchekedradiobutton" />
</selector>
```

Assim você pode definir o `android:button` como `radio_button_personalizado`:

#### Screenshot

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Detalhes

- [Custom Radio Button in Android](http://www.limbaniandroid.com/2014/05/custom-radio-buttons-example-in-android.html)
- [Customizing Radio Button](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/customizing-radio-button-in-android.html)

Comment: Boa, me ajudou aqui.

Comment: @FlavioMisawa conseguiu resolver o problema?!

Comment: Deu certo pra mim sim o/ Valewz